# Why can't I add an element to a list from another class?

Tags: java, arrays, list, class

I have two classes, `Pizza` and `PizzaTopping`. In `Pizza` is an `ArrayList` which should store strings (the pizza topping). I am trying to add an element to the array from the `ham` method in the `PizzaTopping` class. However, when I print the list it shows to be empty. Why?

Here is PizzaTopping:

```
public class PizzaTopping {

    Pizza p = new Pizza();

    public void ham() {
        double cost = 1;
        System.out.println("im in ham");
        p.addToPizza("ham");
        p.setCost(p.getCost() + cost);
    }
}
```

Here is my Pizza class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Pizza {

    private double cost;
    ArrayList<String> pizza = new ArrayList<String>();

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public void addToPizza(String x) {
        System.out.println("im in add");
        pizza.add(x);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        //scanner to add topping
        PizzaTopping pt = new PizzaTopping();
        Pizza p = new Pizza();
        pt.ham();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.pizza.toArray()));
    }

}
```

Comment: 'any ideas what i have done wrong?' - no mention of pepperoni.

Comment: Your class association is messed up. A `PizzaTopping` should not contain a reference of `Pizza`. It should be the other way around. Also, you should make sure that `PizzaTopping`are not shared between `Pizza` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
PizzaTopping pt = new PizzaTopping();
pt.ham();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pt.p.pizza.toArray()));
```

The problem was that you were creating a new pizza object inside main and were not using the one tied to pt so the ham method was saving values inside pt.p and not in p(that you created in main method)

Comment: how could i use a third class (PizzaBase) to also add to the same list?

Comment: well that question is out of context(sorry), you should try yourself first, and believe me its really simple! :)

Comment: i can only get it to print the toppings or the base, not both. Unless i make it static which i would prefer not to do

Comment: by the way, try learning more about Is-a Has-a relationships, it will help you write better Object Oriented code, ex pizza class should contain pizzaToppings object and pizzaBase object, that way we can say that Pizza HAS-A PizzaToppings and PizzaBase, which is technically correct, maybe these things will help you find your solution :)

Comment: @calmcalmuncle, for a better implementation, see my answer. Your object relationships were messed up to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Pizza` class should probably have a default or a no-argument constructor to make a cheese pizza (with some sauce).  It should provide an `.addTopping(PizzaTopping topping) to allow adding topping to it. In theory, there should be an unlimited number of topping that you can add. However, to control the number of toppings, you can probably limit them by adding them to an array (or some`Collections` object).

```
public class Pizza
{
    private List<PizzaTopping> toppings = new ArrayList<PizzaTopping>();

    public Pizza() {} // constructs basic cheese pizza

    public void addTopping(PizzaTopping topping) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if (toppings == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Topping cannot be null");
        toppings.add(new PizzaTopping(topping.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Pizza with " + toppings.size() + " toppings: " + toppings.toString();
    }
}
```

The `PizzaTopping` class should probably have a single-argument constructor (String) to provide the name of the topping.

```
public PizzaTopping
{
    private String name;

    public PizzaTopping(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if (name == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name cannot be null");
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Your test class should simply create the toppings, the pizza, and add the toppings to the pizza.  Each class has a convenience method (`toString()`) to print out information about the object. The toppings prints out its name and the pizza prints out the number of toppings and what the toppings are.  (This is untested code but should work.)

The reason for adding a new instance of `PizzaTopping` to the pizza, is because toppings should not be shared between different `Pizza` instances. Also, you should make sure that you check for null objects if they should not be allowed. Throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` for null objects is a good way that these illegal arguments do not make it (or break) into your code.